# Azure DevOps Pipeline CMD task [error]Access is denied

Tags: azure, batch-file, cmd, azure-devops, agent

I was trying to kill a process CJobs.exe using agent job command line execution task in Azure release pipeline.
My command is:

```
start /b cmd /c taskkill /IM "CJobs.exe" /F
exit
```

but it is giving me this error:

```
##[error]ERROR: The process "CJobs.exe" with PID 12569 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

So if any one knows solution for this problem, please help.
ask if more details required in comments.

Comment: Is it in a Self-hosted agent? if yes, to the user that tun the pipeline have admin permissions in the machine?

Comment: Yes it is a self hosted agent @ShaykiAbramczyk, tun the pipeline means ?

Comment: run* sorry... each pipeline run by some user (the agent installed with some user)

Comment: Try using administrator acount

Comment: @NekoMusume, my account is admin account

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk the user which installed agent, needs to be administrator ?

Comment: @user13483696 is not must, but maybe he needs admin permissions to kill some services

Comment: @user13483696 How about trying `wmic process where name='myprocessname.exe' delete`

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT already tried that but got same error with this too.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the log on account of the self-hosted agent in the local service and change the account to the account you need to perform the operation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thankyou i will check this, and will get back to you

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error was solved when I did this configuration on the Azure Pipeline Agent service: I selected the option "Allow service to interact with desktop".

[Configuration Services Azure Pipeline Agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgsoo.png)

In this way, after restart the service, the pipeline executed successful.